# Vue - Click handler in repeated div will not force update by itself, need to do it manually

Tags: vue.js

When I have a click handler in a div that is repeated with `v-for`, it seems like changes made in that click handler will not be updated in the DOM.

Why?

https://jsfiddle.net/AndersBillLinden/109uzsx7/27/

html:

```html
<div id="vue">
  <input type="checkbox" v-model="force_update"/> force update
  <div v-for="e in arr">
    {{e.id}} = {{e.text}}
    <a href="#" @click="on_link_clicked(e)">click</a>
    <span v-show="e.clicked"> clicked</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```js
new window.Vue(
{
  el: '#vue',
  data:
  {
    arr: [{id:1,text:"one"}, {id:2, text:"two"}, {id:3, text:"three"}],
    force_update: true
  },
  methods:
  {
    on_link_clicked(e)
    {
      e.clicked = true;
      
      if (this.force_update)
        this.$forceUpdate();
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

clicking link 1

[image]

unchecking force update

[image]

clicking the 2nd link

[image]

(nothing happens)

checking "force update"

[image]

Now the changes in the previous step are rendered.

The conclusion is that we sometimes needs to force the update, but it is unclear why.

Comment: there is no clicked in the original model so it wont be reactive, use `this.$set(e, 'clicked', true)` https://jsfiddle.net/g4fq3e76/

Comment: So it cannot detect that is was going from undefined to true then?

Comment: not if it's not defined first in `arr` items

Comment: I like the freedom of doing like this, becaue I am used to it from angularjs.

Comment: thanks for accept, also note that data should return a function, which returns an object `data: () => ({})` etc, not `data: {}`

Comment: But how come that vue accepts an object instead of a function then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `e.clicked = true;` to `this.$set(e, 'clicked', true)` so it adds reactivity to the property which is not already in the model.